# Babel hyphenation not working

Tags: babel, hyphenation

I am having trouble using the `babel` (2016/04/23 3.9r) package. For some reason, soft `babelhyphen` or the `"-` shorthand only add a breaking opportunity but no hyphen is displayed in case a word is broken. This is undesired and results in the following output. Am I doing something wrong, is this a decision by design or just a bug in the update-to-date `babel`/`MiKTeX`?

### Update

After reducing the `parbox` space, I receive the following output. The `"-`shorthand is working but `babelhyphen` not.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

    \bigskip
    \parbox{1em}{$n$\babelhyphen{soft}dimensional}

    \bigskip
    \parbox{1em}{$n$"-dimensional}

    \bigskip
    \parbox{1em}{$n$\-dimensional}

    \bigskip
    \parbox{1em}{$n$\babelhyphen{nobreak}dimensional}

\end{document}
```

### First Version

[image: Output]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

    \bigskip
    \parbox{3em}{n\babelhyphen{soft}dimensional}

    \bigskip
    \parbox{3em}{n"-dimensional}

    \bigskip
    \parbox{3em}{n\-dimensional}

    \bigskip
    \parbox{3em}{n\babelhyphen{nobreak}dimensional}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be `$n$-dimensional` anyhow.

Comment: `3em` may be too wide to see much going on. Replace `3em` with, say, `1mm`, to see some more action.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I removed it to make the example as minimal as possible.

Comment: Your image doesn't show a break at "- or babelhyphen.

Comment: Imho it is a bug. There is a \nobreak missing before `\hskip\z@skip` in the definition of `\bbl@usehyphen`. Write the author of babel.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the help, I'll inform the author of this issue.

Comment: I'll have a look at it.